# How do I code smooth transitions between components?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, vite

I'm making my own single page application and I don't want the content to be static as I scroll down. I want it to ease in with a smooth animation. I couldn't find any guides on the subject. Here is a perfect example of what I'm talking about: qanplatform.com , as you scroll down the content has these nice transitions between components. Is it code-splitting?

so basically i have my:

```
<div className='App'>
  <Navbar/>
  <Hero/>
  <Stats/>
  <Business/>
  <Team/>
  <Footer/>
</div>
```

and I want every component to render with a simple animation only when I scroll down to it and not before. I don't need anyone to write code for me, all I need is a tip on how to proceed. I think qanplatform.com best represents what my idea is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this alternative one quite simple without an intersection observer, combining the CSS animation keyframes and JS to detect and reveal the content height

article: https://alvarotrigo.com/blog/css-animations-scroll/

```js
function reveal() {
  var reveals = document.querySelectorAll(".reveal");

  for (var i = 0; i < reveals.length; i++) {
    var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var elementTop = reveals[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
    var elementVisible = 150;

    if (elementTop < windowHeight - elementVisible) {
      reveals[i].classList.add("active");
    } else {
      reveals[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", reveal);
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Asap&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Asap", sans-serif;
}
body {
  background: #42455a;
}
section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
section:nth-child(1) {
  color: #e0ffff;
}
section:nth-child(2) {
  color: #42455a;
  background: #e0ffff;
}
section:nth-child(3) {
  color: #e0ffff;
}
section:nth-child(4) {
  color: #42455a;
  background: #e0ffff;
}
section .container {
  margin: 100px;
}
section h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin: 20px;
}
section h2 {
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
section .text-container {
  display: flex;
}
section .text-container .text-box {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #00c2cb;
}
section .text-container .text-box h3 {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  section h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
  }
  section .text-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

.reveal {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
}

.reveal.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
.active.fade-bottom {
  animation: fade-bottom 1s ease-in;
}
.active.fade-left {
  animation: fade-left 1s ease-in;
}
.active.fade-right {
  animation: fade-right 1s ease-in;
}
@keyframes fade-bottom {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(50px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes fade-left {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fade-right {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>Scroll Down to Reveal Elements &#8595;</h1>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="container reveal fade-bottom">
    <h2>Caption</h2>
    <div class="text-container">
      <div class="text-box">
        <h3>Section Text</h3>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore
          eius molestiae perferendis eos provident vitae iste.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="text-box">
        <h3>Section Text</h3>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore
          eius molestiae perferendis eos provident vitae iste.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="text-box">
        <h3>Section Text</h3>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore
          eius molestiae perferendis eos provident vitae iste.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="container reveal fade-left">
    <h2>Caption</h2>
    <div class="text-container">
      <div class="text-box">
        <h3>Section Text</h3>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore
          eius molestiae perferendis eos provident vitae iste.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="text-box">
        <h3>Section Text</h3>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore
          eius molestiae perferendis eos provident vitae iste.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="text-box">
        <h3>Section Text</h3>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore
          eius molestiae perferendis eos provident vitae iste.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="container reveal fade-right">
    <h2>Caption</h2>
    <div class="text-container">
      <div class="text-box">
        <h3>Section Text</h3>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore
          eius molestiae perferendis eos provident vitae iste.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="text-box">
        <h3>Section Text</h3>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore
          eius molestiae perferendis eos provident vitae iste.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="text-box">
        <h3>Section Text</h3>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore
          eius molestiae perferendis eos provident vitae iste.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) for new elements entering into view. After that, applying styles has animation on newly entered elements. You can utilise the same technique in React with [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) if you don't want to use class names or inline styles.

```js
const intersectionCallback = (entries) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      //add a new class
      entry.target.classList.add('fade-in-up');
    }
  });
}



const options = {
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 0 //when it just appear in your viewport, you can modify it based on your needs
}

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(intersectionCallback, options);

//find all elements which have a class name `content` to observe, you can use React's refs as well
const contentElements = document.querySelectorAll('.content')

for (const contentElement of contentElements) {
  observer.observe(contentElement)
}
```

```css
@keyframes fadeInUp {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/*Animation styles*/
.fade-in-up {
  opacity: 0;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-name: fadeInUp;
}

.content {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1>
    Scroll down to see the animation
  </h1>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <h1>
    Scroll down to see the animation
  </h1>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <h1>
    End
  </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Animate On Scroll (AOS)](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/) or [GSAP](https://greensock.com/gsap/) for this!

They're both pretty easy to use but for this example I'll use AOS since it's quite simpler:

```js
// Initialize the lbrary after the page loads
AOS.init();
```

```css
/* Basic styling (not needed) */

div {
  margin-top: 50vh;
  
}
```

```html
<!-- Add the required libraries for AOS -->
<link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>

<body>
  <div data-aos="fade-up">This element fades up on scroll</div>
  <div data-aos="fade-up">This element fades up on scroll</div>
  <div data-aos="fade-up">This element fades up on scroll</div>
  
  <div data-aos="fade-right">This element fades right on scroll</div>
  <div data-aos="fade-right">This element fades right on scroll</div>
  <div data-aos="fade-right">This element fades right on scroll</div>
  <div data-aos="fade-right">This element fades right on scroll</div>
  <div data-aos="fade-right">This element fades right on scroll</div>
  <div data-aos="fade-right">This element fades right on scroll</div>
  
  More examples in the AOS homepage
</body>
```

To use this in react just import the libraries